# Keycloak default setting in docker

Tags: containers, keycloak

What parameter when running keycloak in the container allows me to set Duplicate emails to "ON". Default is "OFF".
Manual change does not satisfy me. I need to change it to "ON" every time I deploy it.

[keycloak realm settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLt3k.png)

I checked the keycloak documentation, but unfortunately I can't find the answer anywhere.
I also checked on forums and other websites, you are the last hope.